# Kali Linux on Macbook 4 1

Tags: boot, kali-linux, hard-disk, macintosh

I've decided to install Kali Linux on my friend's Macbook. I've had an extra empty hard disk that I've removed from my old PC. First, I removed the old hard disk and inserted mine and thought I could boot Kali Linux from a USB, it seemed like working but after the completion of the installation, Macbook didn't boot in Kali Linux because I've received a grub bootloader installation error. I also tried to install Windows 10 to see if it is going to be successful, but windows kept reinstalling itself. What exactly is the problem here? or Is there a way for me to install grub bootloader to a Mac without a working OS.

Comment: The Mac boot process is different from a PC. http://www.rodsbooks.com/ubuntu-efi/ might help.